# How do use a command where you changed its installation directory in linux?

Tags: linux

Hello I am on a linux server running 2.6.18-274.e15.  I have installed a program called scons in order to compile a program called rosetta.  In order to get scons to install when I ran it's python install I used the following command

```
python setup.py install flexed --prefix=.
```

This was because I am unable to use the folder it was trying to download into with my user status.  When I call "scons --version" I am getting "command not found".

What I am wondering:
Is running scons even possible with my setup?
If so, what command would I use?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the install path in your `$PATH`?

Comment: EDIT:I don't have permission to check that folder come to find out.  Is there any work around to this?

Comment: See @devsnd's answer.  Basically you installed to the current directory that you issued the `python setup.py` command (namely the `.` directory).  There is perhaps a subdirectory there called `bin`, which should contain the `scons` binary/executable.  It is that subdirectory that you need to append to your `$PATH` as in @devsnd's answer.

Comment: Sorry about the previous comment I tried to get that edit off before you commented back.  I don't have access to the $path file.  When I try to get there using /etc/bashrc I get a permission denied.  I assume now its about time to ask the IT guy to change the $path for me?

Comment: You shouldn't need to modify `/etc/bashrc`, which is a system-wide file.  You should have a local bashrc file in `~/.bashrc` where you can add that command.  If the file doesn't exist, simply create it.

Comment: Apparently it didn't make it into $path so I ran devsnd's suggestion.  I think I over thought what was going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the directory of your binary to your path, in the shell:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/the/dir/of/your/binary
```

Comment: I feel like I should have know this answer.  Thanks.